# Count Most donator SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to know how would i count most donated number for a person and how to make list from most donator to the lowest.

Database looks like this :

```
 - Donated Amount - Payer Email
 - 10   123456@hotmail.com
 - 5    125643@hotmail.com
 - 5    123456o@gmail.com
 - 20   6653211@live.de
 - 5    1256431@live.de
 - 10   6558714@gmail.com
```

Note : If anyone would guide me on how the table is made on stackoverflow, thank you.

Comment: `order by Donated_Amount desc` ??

Comment: GROUP BY, SUM etc.

Comment: My I suggest a basic [Sql tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, if someone made several donations sum() is needed.

Comment: "Database looks like this".  That is `Table`, not `Database`

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to group by the email, sum the amount to get a total, and order by descending total.

```
SELECT 
 `Payer Email`, 
 SUM(`Donated Amount`) AS DonatedAmount
-- , COUNT(*) AS TimesDonated
-- , MAX(`Donated Amount`) AS BiggestDonation
FROM YourDonationsTable
GROUP BY `Payer Email`
ORDER BY DonatedAmount DESC
```

And if you want only the top 3 of those, add a `LIMIT 3` at the end of the SQL.

Comment: Thx. Btw, I used a group by because one probably doesn't know if someone donated more than once.  Otherwise you just need an ORDER BY the donated amount.